# What am I doing wrong? and/or in Python

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm new at this.

Here's the question:

Write a program that takes a position on a chess board as a column col and row value row and checks whether or not the position is valid. Remember that the column in a chess board is a letter ranging from A to H (inclusive) and the row is a number between 1 and 8 (inclusive). A3 or E7 are valid inputs but a1 or L5 are not. If both coordinates are valid, such as E2, the programs prints 'The piece is moved to E2.', otherwise it prints 'The position is not valid.'.

Here's my code:

```
if row <9 and col == 'A' or col ==  'B' or col ==  'C' or col == 'D' or col ==  'E' or col == 'F'  or col == 'G' or col == 'H':

    print "The piece is moved to",col,row,"."
else:

    print "The position is not valid."
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not the problem, but all your `col == ''` could be replaced by the cleaner looking `col in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']` (or `col in list('ABCDEFGH')`)
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in some parentheses to make sure all the column checks are treated vs. the row query:

```
if row <9 and (col == 'A' or col ==  'B' or col ==  'C' or col == 'D' or col ==  'E' or col == 'F'  or col == 'G' or col == 'H'):

    print "The piece is moved to",col,row,"."
else:

    print "The position is not valid."
```

BTW, your code doesn't check for column = 0, and a simpler way would be to say:

```
if (row in range(1,9) and col in "ABCDEFGH"):
```

You can print the string together using either `.format()` or the `%` operator:

```
print "The piece is moved to {}{}.".format(col,row)
```

or

```
print "The piece is moved to %s%d." % (col,row)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to delete the whitespace between col & row?

Comment: Note that `col in "ABCDEFGH"` works even if `col` is `ABC`. Of course if you are sure your input is a single character you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: True, Null. If they want to make sure they could say `in list("ABCDEFGH")` but that seems unlikely.

Comment: even better would be to use tuple("ABCDEFGH"), as it is unmutable and consumes a bit less resources.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses! You need them because, like in maths, it will do everything in the parentheses first, then something else.